# Output for Esper sliding window seams when an event come after another leave

Tags: event-handling, esper, sliding-window, event-listener

From Esper sample, i just write simple EPL like this :

```
select symbol, avg(price) as avgprice,count(*) as count,            
current_timestamp() as time from StockTick.win:time(0.4 sec)
group by symbol
```

And each 100 millisecond, I feed data into Esper as follow :

```
StockTick={symbol='YHOO', price=100}
t=t.plus(0.1 seconds)
StockTick={symbol='YHOO', price=65}
t=t.plus(0.1 seconds)
StockTick={symbol='YHOO', price=75}
t=t.plus(0.1 seconds)
StockTick={symbol='YHOO', price=65}
t=t.plus(0.1 seconds)
StockTick={symbol='YHOO', price=100}
t=t.plus(0.1 seconds)
StockTick={symbol='YHOO', price=15}
```

But the output i receive make me confused

```
Statement: AVGTABLE
Insert
AVGTABLE-output={symbol='YHOO', avgprice=76.25, count=4, time=300}
At: 1970-01-01 00:00:00.400
Statement: AVGTABLE
Insert
AVGTABLE-output={symbol='YHOO',avgprice=68.33333333333333, count=3,     
time=400}
At: 1970-01-01 00:00:00.400
Statement: AVGTABLE
Insert
AVGTABLE-output={symbol='YHOO', avgprice=76.25, count=4, time=400}
At: 1970-01-01 00:00:00.500
Statement: AVGTABLE
Insert
AVGTABLE-output={symbol='YHOO', avgprice=80.0, count=3, time=500}
At: 1970-01-01 00:00:00.500
Statement: AVGTABLE
Insert
AVGTABLE-output={symbol='YHOO', avgprice=63.75, count=4, time=500}
At: 1970-01-01 00:00:00.600
Statement: AVGTABLE
Insert
AVGTABLE-output={symbol='YHOO', avgprice=60.0, count=3, time=600}
```

At time 400 and 500, there are 2 outputs here, and i guess it appears due to 1 event leave of window before another come. Why are they appear here since i dont select `irstream` and how can i avoid it in `UpdateEventListener`?

Answer (score 0):

When events expire from the time window the average changes therefore the listener sees the new average, since the old average is no longer correct. Avoid it by not using a time window so for instance `... from StockTick group by ...`

Comment: I used time window for calculate average of price for last 1 days. So in this case, can u give me a hint?